# Position: absolute behaving differently in safari

Tags: css, html, safari, position, absolute

I am building a responsive website ( http://dev.searsdavies.co.uk/quadrant-new/ )

With a layout that requires a set of buttons to sit in the dead centre of the screen for portrait tablets, this layout is triggered at a screen width of 768px and stays in place down to 414px. The buttons are position:absolute on top of all the other content as they need to snap to the bottom on the larger and smaller versions of the site.

The boxes behave perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but safari positions them too high up the page.

Full site is above, here is the relevant CSS

```
.row.footer {
    bottom: 49%;
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

.row.full-width {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

There is also a conditional query that stops the layout becoming too shallow on landscape phones and similar devices:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 800px) and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:415px) {

        .row.footer {
            top:352px ;
            bottom:auto ;
            transform:none
        }
    }

.side-img {
        height: 50vh;
        min-height: 400px;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
    }
    .main-content {
        height: 50vh;
        min-height: 400px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here.

**Firstly**, [prefix your properties](http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms); you are using `transform` but you are **not** prefixing; they will not work in Safari.

`webkit-transform: translate(x,x);`

**Secondly**, you have this in your `@media` query - `max-height: 800px`. That means `do this stuff when the browser is **less than** 800px in height` - **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e79ofaez/)**.

Is that ***really*** what you want to say for a `@media` rule targeting a portrait tablet (an iPad for [example](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/), has is `768 width`by `1024 height`)?

To fix your issues:

1) prefix your `transforms`

2) fix your `@media` rules

3) remove the `bottom: auto` rule

4) remove/adjust the `bottom: 49%` rule

Comment: thanks for this, keeping the media rule as is however because the 2 content divs have min-height of 400px, so this rule is purely targetting the very specific screen size where that kicks in. I have another query entirely targetting the correct ipad resolution of 1024 x 768, not 786 as you mentioned

Comment: the browser prefixes did fix my issue, thanks very much for your help, I thought transform was well supported by now but evidently now

Comment: @MikeSmith  be sure to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you; the `786` was a typo, damn these fingers...also note, resolution reads as **width x height** - the resolution is `768 x 1024`; just keep in mind the syntax